# Why does CDT have different repository for Kepler/Juno/Indigo?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-kepler

The CDT repositories are different for Kepler/Juno/Indigo.
Kepler: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler 
Juno: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno
Indigo: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo
Also, I noticed that CDT version for Kepler is the latest, juno and indigo have relatively older CDT versions. 
I wanted to have latest CDT version in Juno. Will it cause any harm if I upgrade the CDT in Juno using the kepler repository?

Comment: The install will probably fail because the Kepler CDT will require the Kepler versions of the core Eclipse plugins.

Comment: Installing works fine. But I am not sure if there may be any compatibility problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent releases of Eclipse have had synchronized releases of most of the different components (Platform, JDT, PDE, CDT, ....). These components have all been tested to work with each other so you should not have any problems with installation or missing APIs.

You may be able to use newer versions of a component (such as CDT) with an older release. However you may find the install fails because the component requires newer versions of the core plugins. If it does install you are using a combination which has had less testing.